# Last Touch Attribution in MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

```
  Conversions

  user_id   | tag       | timestamp           
|---------  |--------   |---------------------|
| 1         | click1    | 2016-11-01 01:20:39 |
| 2         | click2    | 2016-11-01 09:48:10 |
| 3         | click1    | 2016-11-04 14:27:22 |
| 4         | click4    | 2016-11-05 17:50:14 |
```

```
  User Sessions

  user_id   | utm_campaign      | session_start           
|---------  |---------------    |---------------------|
| 1         | outbrain_2        | 2016-11-01 00:15:34 |
| 1         | email             | 2016-11-01 01:00:29 |
| 2         | google_1          | 2016-11-01 08:24:39 |
| 3         | google_4          | 2016-11-04 14:25:06 |
| 4         | google_1          | 2016-11-05 17:43:02 |
```

Given the 2 tables above, I want to map each conversion event to the most recent campaign that brought a particular user to a site (aka last touch/last click attribution).

The desired output is a table of the format:

```
  user_id   | tag       | timestamp           | campaign
|---------  |--------   |---------------------|-----------
| 1         | click1    | 2016-11-01 01:20:39 | email
| 2         | click2    | 2016-11-01 09:48:10 | google_1
| 3         | click1    | 2016-11-04 14:27:22 | google_4
| 4         | click4    | 2016-11-05 17:50:14 | google_1
```

Note how user 1 visited the site via the outbrain_2 campaign and then came back to the site via the email campaign. Sometime during the user's second visit, they converted, thus the conversion should be attributed to email and not outbrain_2.

Is there a way to do this in MySQL or Python?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Python with Pandas. I assume you can load the data from MySQL tables to Pandas dataframes `conversions` and `sessions`. First, concatenate both tables:

```
all = pd.concat([conversions,sessions])
```

Some of the elements in the new frame will be NAs. Create a new column that collects the time stamps from both tables:

```
all["ts"] = np.where(all["session_start"].isnull(),
    all["timestamp"],
    all["session_start"])
```

Sort by this column, forward fill the time values, group by the user ID, and select the last (most recent) row from each group:

```
groups = all.sort_values("ts").ffill().groupby("user_id",as_index=False).last()
```

Select the right columns:

```
result = groups[["user_id", "tag", "timestamp", "utm_campaign"]]
```

I tried this code with your sample data and got the right answer.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like it's almost there. I tried a scenario where user 1 has a 3rd session which started after the conversion. The methodology here attributes the conversion to the 3rd session instead of the second. Is there a way to address this?